# Mako template depending on object class?

Tags: python, mako

whats a clean way to use different templates depending on an object class?  other than buncha if statements

Comment: When working in Python, doing different things based on the type of an object is almost always a design flaw. Perhaps you should pre-process your data so that the template can access it in a straightforward manner?

Comment: i will do that, i just realizes what i might be doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `dict`, call it `type2templ`, with types (i.e., classes) as the keys, and `mako.template.Template` instances as the values -- then

```
t = type2templ.get(type(theobj), default_templ)
... t.render() ...
```

This assumes that `theobj` is an instance of a *new-style* class (not the obsolete, best-avoided "legacy" classes that are still the default in Python 2 -- if you use those, you should **definitely** upgrade your code to new-style classes, but using `theobj.__class__` is a workable, if hackish, replacement for `type(theobj)` here).  `default_templ` is a default template instance to use for "none of the above" (if you'd rather have an exception when `theobj` is of a non-recognized type, use square-bracket indexing instead of the `.get` call).

Note that this doesn't (directly) "support inheritance" -- if (for example) class `foo` maps in `type2templ` to template `bar`, then you make a subclass `baz` of `foo` but don't explicitly record in `type2templ` what template its instances should use, you'll get the default template for `baz`'s instances.  Supporting inheritance is more complex -- unless you just make the mako template instance one of the class attributes, of course, which makes it trivial (just `theobj.thetempl` if you name that attribute `thetempl`!-), but I do understand to separate the view from the model.